# Laravel Blade Vue - Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I am trying to pass a variable from Blade to a Vue component prop. However, when I'm passing the variable, something goes wrong. The error which I receive is the following:

```
[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

invalid expression: Invalid or unexpected token in

    [{"id":6,"name":"aaa","created_at":"2019-12-05

  Raw expression: :companies="[{"id":6,"name":"aaa","created_at":"2019-12-05"


153|                      <!-- Page Content -->
154|  
155|      <company_index :companies="[{&quot;id&quot;:6,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;aaa&quot;,&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;2019-12-05" 14:35:38&quot;,&quot;updated_at&quot;:&quot;2019-12-05="" 14:35:38&quot;}]=""></company_index>
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
156|      <!-- END Page Content -->
157|              </main>

(found in <Root>)
```

As you can see, a random quote is added which is NOT present in the datetime itself (after `2019-12-05`). It only gets added when passing it to the Vue component. Here is my code from my blade file:

```
@extends('layouts.backend')

@section('content')
    <!-- Page Content -->

    <company_index :companies={{json_encode($companies)}}></company_index>
    <!-- END Page Content -->
@endsection
```

I've tried the following things:

- Checked to see if the datetime somehow had an extra quote, this was not the case.
- Checked if other Eloquent Models had the same problems, which they do (They also use standard datetimes from Laravel).
- Remove `json_encode` from my blade file
- Replaced `:companies={{json_encode($companies)}` with `:companies={!! $companies !!}`
- Searched for people with the same problem, but did not find anything about this problem.

I don't think there is anything wrong with my code, but I don't know for sure what my problem is. If you need more details, just ask.

Comment: try adding double quote? :companies="{{json_encode($companies)}}"

Comment: @JesusErwinSuarez Add your comment as an answer good job

Comment: I just posted, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding double quote `:companies="{{json_encode($companies)}}"`